# Alternative to using multiple quotation marks in a sentence for easier reading?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

A character is going through file names on a computer. Short works usually go in quotes instead of being italicized, but is there a way to make this read less clunkily?

> I went to his folder labeled “School Stuff.” I opened it and clicked on “Homework.” There was “Holodomor,” “The American Revolution,” “Book Report,” and “Huckleberry Finn.”

Comment: If editing, I'd remove all those quotes.

Comment: Your answer is probably found here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170458/correct-way-to-enumerate-ideas-in-english

Comment: There isn't a hard-and-fast rule for file names in the way there is for book titles; especially in fiction you are free to use whatever representation you want, whether single or double quotes, italics, capitalised terms with no quote marks, or something else. So you could use italics or remove the quotation marks. (Some publications have a style guide for fiction, but it is unlikely to prescribe something for file names. And some publications differ on titles of books, stories, or songs.)

Comment: This is an important question. In a technical description of a computer user’s action, it’s important to be consistent, and we’re often willing to accept a certain amount of awkwardness in order to achieve clarity of meaning. In fiction writing, our objectives are different. It would be interesting to see some opinions here, since there’s a whole range of writing that falls between strict accuracy and complete fiction. I’m thinking of sales and marketing material, but journalists and other story tellers would also benefit from a generally-accepted style.